# \definecolor{}{}{} why this value work 0,255,255 and this 26,160,224 not?

Tags: color

I'm wondering why, my line 1 works (and produce a cyan color) and line 2 doesn’t. the value (26, 120, 224) are RGB value that I've picked wit GIMP, so I think they're correct.

1. `\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0,255,255}`
2. `\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{26,160,224}`

Comment: The correct syntax is `\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{26,160,224}`, rgb in lowercase needs numbers between 0 and 1. If you use larger numbers, they are rounded down, so your second declaration is (1,1,1) and so white.

Comment: oh didn't see your comment before posting my answer ;) @UlrikeFischer

Comment: so the differences is just in rgb and RGB :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a mistake in the error specification. Note that the model `rgb` means that your values should be between `0` and `1`, whereas `RGB` means that your values should be between `0` and `255` (like you chose).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{a}{rgb}{0,1,1}
\definecolor{b}{rgb}{0.39,0.62,0.88}
\definecolor{A}{RGB}{0, 255, 255}
\definecolor{B}{RGB}{26, 160, 224}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{My title}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item {\color{a}this is colored a}
            \item {\color{b}this is colored b}
            \item {\color{A}this is colored A}
            \item {\color{B}this is colored B}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See how both the defined colors `a` and `A` as well as `b` and `B` are the same?

Cheers, k

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've found my solution.